# ¿Como selecciono un tag o lo creo si no existe usando select2 js?

Tags: javascript, select2

Estoy tratando de crear un campo estilo "Tags de Categorias" , del que pueda seleccionar una opción (Previamente cargada en un array) y si no existiera la opción crearla y agregarla al array previamente cargado.

Este es mi codigo html:

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single form-control" name="state" multiple="multiple">

</select>
```

Y este es mi codigo Javascript:

```
<script>
     var data = [
       {
            id: 0,
            text: 'enhancement'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            text: 'bug'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            text: 'duplicate'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            text: 'invalid'
         },
         {
            id: 4,
            text: 'wontfix'
         }
       ];

$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
                 data: data,
                 tags:true,
                 tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
                 createTag: function (params) {
                        var term = $.trim(params.term);
                        if (term === '') {
                          return null;
                        }
                          return {
                            id: term,
                            text: term,
                            newTag: true // add additional parameters
                          }
                        },
                    });
                });

                console.log(data);

 </script>
```

He logrado que el dom se comporte como deseo es decir que funcionen los tags y que pueda agregar mas , pero en general no se ni entiendo en la documentacion como utililizar los tags (ni los cargados anteriormente ni los nuevos creados).

Al utilizar el console.log no pinta nada en consola.

Comment: Esas tags no las cargas de una base de datos?

Comment: No en la siguiente fase del proyecto lo haré, por ahora estoy intentando con data Dummy pero no logro “utilizar” el módulo Select2 para hacer algo con el.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que utilizar el evento `select2:select` este evento sera lanzado cada vez que se seleccione un tag este o no creado en `data`. Con este evento tan solo tendremos que buscar si ese tag seleccionado existe y si no existe lo insertamos en nuestro `data`.

El codigo quedaria asi.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
          content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <select class="js-example-basic-single form-control"
            name="state"
            style="width: 100px !important;height: 100px !important;"
            multiple="multiple">

    </select>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var data = [
            {
                id: 0,
                text: 'enhancement'
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                text: 'bug'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                text: 'duplicate'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                text: 'invalid'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                text: 'wontfix'
            }
        ];

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var select = $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
                data: data,
                tags: true,
                tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
            });


            select.on('select2:select', function (e) { // Evento cada vez que se seleccion un tag
                var existTag = data.some(tag => tag.id == e.params.data.id); // Busca en data si ya existe ese tag
                if (!existTag) {
                    var simulateUuid = new Date().getTime();
                    data.push({ id: simulateUuid, text: e.params.data.text });
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```